# adb push does not copy well

Tags: android, adb

I have a problem using the command `adb push`. When I push inside a loop is not performed on the first iteration, the rest itself.

Any idea?

```
public void export_APK(String dir, String nom_fich, String dir_padre) throws IOException, InterruptedException{ 


        Process p6;

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c adb wait-for-device");               
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c adb install -r " + dir);

            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell rm -r /sdcard/Alumno");        
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell mount /sdcard");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell mkdir /sdcard/Alumno");            



  for (Integer i=1;i<6;i++){                              
    p6 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb push c:\image\photo" + i + " /sdcard/Alumno/Actividad"+i);            
    p6.waitFor();                
  }                                     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

// your for loop is wrong

```
   for (int i=1;i<6;i++){                              
    Process p6 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb push c:\image\photo" + i + " /sdcard/Alumno/Actividad"+i);            
    p6.waitFor(); 
Log.d("Inside loop","---i==="+i);

      }
```

Comment: I understand your correction but I do not understand as it concerns the problem as it always fails in the first push.
 Still I have corrected the condition but still same thing happening in the first iteration does not do the push

Comment: p6 is a process. // Process p6;

Comment: @user1177917 check my edited answer. can you try to print the log cat and check how many times it is executing.

Comment: I did the debug, I see the console that performs all iterations but in the end (sd card) are all pictures except those of the first iteration                                                             Copy-> c:\image\photo1 /sdcard/Alumno/Actividad1
Copy-> c:\image\photo2 /sdcard/Alumno/Actividad2
Copy-> c:\image\photo3 /sdcard/Alumno/Actividad3
Copy-> c:\image\photo4 /sdcard/Alumno/Actividad4
Copy-> c:\image\photo5 /sdcard/Alumno/Actividad5

Comment: put i=2 and try it. I am leave by cu 2morrow.